# How to get a Test Bench file to integrate another VHDL defined part?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am trying to figure out why this test bench is not using the flip-flop assigned when simulating.

Here is the D flip-flop I created:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
entity dff_hw is
     port (clk : in std_logic;
             rst : in std_logic;
             d : in std_logic;
             q : out std_logic);
end dff_hw;
architecture Behavioral of dff_hw is
    begin
     dff_hw_proc : process (clk, rst)
         begin
         if (rst = '1') then
             q <= '0';
         elsif rising_edge(clk) then
                q <= d;
         end if;
     end process dff_hw_proc;
end architecture Behavioral;
```

This is the test bench I wrote:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity hw_dff_tb is
end hw_dff_tb;
architecture behavior of hw_dff_tb is
     -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)
     component hw_dff
         port(
         clk : in std_logic;
         rst : in std_logic;
         d : in std_logic;
         q : out std_logic
         );
     end component;

 --Inputs
 signal hw_dff_tb_clk : std_logic := '0';
 signal hw_dff_tb_rst : std_logic := '0';
 signal hw_dff_tb_d : std_logic := '0';

 --Outputs
 signal hw_dff_tb_q : std_logic;

 -- Clock period definitions
 constant hw_dff_tb_clock_period : time := 10ns;

begin
     -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
     uut : hw_dff port map (
         clk => hw_dff_tb_clk,
         rst => hw_dff_tb_rst,
         d => hw_dff_tb_d,
         q => hw_dff_tb_q);
     -- Clock process definitions
     hw_dff_clock_process : process
     begin
         hw_dff_tb_clk <= '0';
         wait for hw_dff_tb_clock_period/2;
         hw_dff_tb_clk <= '1';
         wait for hw_dff_tb_clock_period/2;
 end process;
 -- Stimulus process
 stim_proc : process
 begin
         -- hold reset state for 100us.
         hw_dff_tb_rst <= '1';
         hw_dff_tb_d <= '0';
         wait for hw_dff_tb_clock_period*2;
         hw_dff_tb_rst <= '0';

         wait for hw_dff_tb_clock_period*1;
         hw_dff_tb_d <= '1';

         wait for hw_dff_tb_clock_period*1;
         hw_dff_tb_d <= '0';

          wait for hw_dff_tb_clock_period*1;
         hw_dff_tb_d <= '1';

         wait for hw_dff_tb_clock_period*1;
         hw_dff_tb_d <= '0';

         wait;
     end process;
end;
```

When I am running the simulation the q output is not doing anything I have even tried to set it in the flip-flop file to just 1 and it stayed at 0 the entire time I was running that test. I know that because it's not working as designed I'm doing something wrong, but being new to VHDL I am not sure what I need to google to figure out what is causing the part to not "drop in" to the test bench.

Comment: Your entity declaration name and and component declaration name don't match while your testbench component declaration and instance name do match. Making them all match and correcting the physical literal (`10ns` should be `10 ns`, a missing space) and your [testbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsuzH.jpg) runs with your flip flop doing something.  Your unit under test was unbound because the names mismatched.

Comment: On a side note, drop `use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;` (<- never use this at all) and `use ieee.numeric_std.all;`, as you're not doing any arithmetic in you test bench.